# Windows XP login at domain takes too long

Tags: windows-xp, login, windows-domain

I have a computer which is connected to network of my office.

We have to login using our username and password with the office's domain name, which is shown when we click *Options* on the right side of the login dialog.

After entering my username and password, when I click "OK", it takes so much time to log in. After that, the system is running fine. Only at the point where I log in, it takes such a long time.

My other colleagues don't have this sort of problem.

- OS: Windows XP SP2
- RAM: 1.25GB
- Hard disk: 160GB

[image]
[image]

Comment: The issues are almost exclusively DNS related. Check your event log. Failing that, http://blogs.technet.com/b/markrussinovich/archive/2010/01/13/3305263.aspx

Comment: SP2?!  Come on with that noise bro.

Comment: Make sure the client time is in sync with the AD server time, Kerberos doesn't like clock skew.

Comment: XP **SP2**? Please unplug the network cable and stangle your admin with that.

Answer (score 2):

A very big thing that slows down Active Directory is syncing your profile. Every time you log on it must check that all of your files are in sync from the Active Directory server. If you are using a slow link or you have a lot of files this can cause it to take a log time to log in.

[Check the size of the profile](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/294887) and if it is over a few megabytes in size that could be your problem.

This can be solved by removing things that are copied when the profile syncs (My Documents, Desktop, %AppData% of old programs, ect.). One good thing to have set up on the domain if most of your space is used up by My Documents or Desktop (and you can't clear it out) is enable [Folder Redirection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Folder_redirection) on the domain for those folders so the files do not need to be copied locally.

Comment: I find that 99% of all slow domain logons are caused by a profile that is too big. Especially when going over a slow connection, a profile of more than several dozen megs will kill your logon performance.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to diagnose this by running [AutoRuns](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963902.aspx) from SysInternals. It will show you what programs auto-start on Windows start-up. By examining each of these files, and unchecking those that are unessential to ensure they aren't contributing to the slow login, you should be able to identify the culprit(s) and either remove them, reconfigure them, or update them with versions that don't have this issue.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to diagnose this by running AutoRuns from SysInternals. It will show you what programs auto-start on Windows start-up. By examining each of these files, and unchecking those that are unessential to ensure they aren't contributing to the slow login, you should be able to identify the culprit(s) and either remove them, reconfigure them, or update them with versions that don't have this issue.

Comment: Hint: there's no need to quote the whole question body.

Comment: Please read [How do I recommend software](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/5329/how-do-i-recommend-software-in-my-answers/5330#5330) for some tips as to how you should go about recommending software. You should provide at least a link, some additional information about the software itself, and how it can be used to solve the problem in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Press <kbd>Windows+R</kbd> then type `eventvwr`

1. Right click the `security` and select `Properties` set maximum log value to `1024` and apply and ok.
2. Right click the `system` and select `Properties` set maximum log value to `1024` and apply and ok.

Comment: While this may answer the question, it would be a better answer if you could provide some explanation **why** it does so.

Comment: System login and security login is full.So we add more memory.

Comment: That's unlikely. [Event log recommended max size is 4GB](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/957662/recommended-settings-for-event-log-sizes-in-windows#appliesto) ...

Comment: Windows XP maintain record for domain login.Its default size is 512 kb,Once the record size reaches the 512 kb the issue will be formed and may show  System login and security login is full.when we add more memory simply resolve the issue.....Thanks NL

Comment: That may be correct. Please provide a source reference and add that information to your answer.

Comment: No source of reference,actually I got information in troubleshooting System in our firm.

Answer (score -2):

1. Install CCleaner [http://www.piriform.com/ccleaner/download/standard], and go to Tools --> Startup to delete any unwanted startup items (which is most of them).  *Don't delete it if you can't figure out what it's for though*
2. Recreate your local profile.  Follow these instructions from Microsoft: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/811151
3. Check your Event Log for startup errors.

Honestly, I believe Step 1 solves 40% of these issues, and Step 2 solves another 40%.

Installing more than 1.25GB RAM will definitely help though, too.  :)